# Private field 'serialVersionUID' is never used: intelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using below code in my springboot API. It works fine when I test in eclipse IDE but returns error in IntelliJ.

```
package com.test.file.business;

public class BoException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1644073898484566119L;

    public BoException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

'Object()' in 'java.lang.Object' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Exception)'

Found problems related to 'com.test.file.business.BoException'

Private field 'serialVersionUID' is never used

Found problems related to 'BoException(Exception)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you want to extend `Exception`

```
public class BoException extends Exception
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the answer above, you should extend the Exception class to be able to call super.
The second problem is unused serialVersionUID. It is used when the class implements Serializable. So your code should look like that:

```
package com.test.file.business;

public class BoException extends Exception implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1644073898484566119L;

    public BoException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

Note that Exception implements Serializable too so that after extending Exception IDE will not warn you anymore.